# How could I add data from Virtuoso to Elasticsearch using logstash and Java?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, logstash, rdf

So I am using JDBC input plugin to import the rdf triples from Virtuoso into Elasticsearch
using Logstash

These are the configuration in the conf file, which I run to import the data

```
jdbc {

    jdbc_driver_library => "C:\Program Files\OpenLink Software\Virtuoso OpenSource 7.2\lib\jdbc-4.0\virtjdbc4.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "Java::virtuoso.jdbc4.Driver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:virtuoso://localhost:1111"
    jdbc_user => "dba"
    jdbc_password => "dba"
    statement => "SELECT CAST(x.s AS varchar) AS s, CAST(x.p AS varchar) AS p, CAST(x.o AS varchar) AS o  FROM (SPARQL Select * from <http://localhost:8890/RDF8> where {?s ?p ?o }) as x"
}
}
```

I wanted to know how can I write a Java program, integrating logstash with Spring and adding the above conf file into the code?

Comment: What happens when you put the code into action? What's not meeting your expectation?

Comment: Worth noting -- we just pushed Virtuoso Open Source 7.2.6.1, which includes updated JDBC drivers, among many other updates and fixes. I don't see anything here that's specifically addressed with this update, but it may be worth applying anyway -- especially for the latest JDBC 4.3 driver (where you're using 4.0), to go with the latest Java.

Comment: @TallTed I am importing by running the command in power shell which runs successfully ,I haven't written any java code to do it . I wanted to know how can I write a Java program, integrating logstash with Spring and adding the above conf file into the code.

Comment: It looks like most of your question was lifted from [our recent how-to](https://community.openlinksw.com/t/connecting-virtuoso-to-elasticsearch-logstash-jdbc/2599). I suggest you reword it to say so, and to ask for what you really want -- which is not "is this possible?" but what you've *just* asked in your comment....